# Windows preventing reg query on HKLM; returns HKCU instead

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, registry, registry-virtualization

I'm using ActivePython 2.5 to read the registry for entries that pGina makes. Specifically, the entries concerning which GIDs are allowed on the computer. This information can periodically change for each computer as edited through pGina, so I want my Python script to be able to check these values each time.

Easy enough. The following Windows command will get that information for me:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\pGina\ldapauth\
```

...except when I run it with Python, I get this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> command = 'reg query HKLM\Software\pGina\ldapauth'
>>> ldapauth = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

So when I run 'reg query HKLM\Software' through Python, it spits out a list of the keys and values under HK **CU**\Software, rather than HKLM.

I'm running Python as Administrator (confirmed by using getpass.getuser()) and when I run the same command from a batch script, I get the correct listing under HKLM. However, when I call the batch script from Python, back to the ole' HKCU results.

So, I'm a bit stuck. Does anyone have any insight?

EDIT: As detailed later, I am running Windows 7 64-bit and I have tried the _winreg methods, including the optional 4th "sam" argument in OpenKey.

Comment: You're running Win7 aren't you? Apparently that implements registry virtualization, which is the likely culprit. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897324/problem-opening-registry-key-on-windows-7) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897324/problem-opening-registry-key-on-windows-7)

Comment: this issue also affects cmakes own `find_library` that many packages rely on to find things. For example cmake cannot find 64bit Python libraries through registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Python\\PythonCore\` because cmake executable is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still haven't found a solution to the root cause in my case. I can, however, work around it. A script run by SYSTEM upon every login will now export the key(s) in question to a text file which can easily be parsed.

Comment: For Win 7 registry virtualization, see e.g. the SO articles I cited in my comment under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [winreg](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html). (`winreg.OpenKey` and `winreg.Query*`). Way faster, no need to thunk out to running a shell command, and it will even return you tricky registry value types like BINARY as well, all in an OO way.

```
#import _winreg as winreg # the 'correct' idiom for importing
from _winreg import *

with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'Software\pGina\ldapauth') as key:
    ... do something with QueryValue(key[,...])
```

winreg does the job fine, although the interface is pretty quirky, since the underlying Windows interface was. You might well like to write a wrapper for the lookup call, esp. if like me you write a generator to get recursion and enumeration of subkeys, pattern-matching to key-names, restrict search to certain allowable registry values etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those examples out on the web. I should have said before that I've tried it and it still returns HKCU.

Comment: There is an optional 4th arg to `OpenKey(hive,keyname[,0,sam])`. sam is [access rights](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html#access-rights), you might also need `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`.

Comment: Windows returning you HKCU when you asked for HKLM sounds like some Windows permissions issue, not Python. I personally ran that sort of command on HKLM no problem. What version of Windows? Is Windows Defender (or third party security software) turned off?

Comment: Suggest you change title to _'Windows preventing reg query on HKLM; returns HKCU instead'_

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, ppl! The 4th argument hasn't made a difference, I'm afraid. Symantec is running, but it seems to make no difference when it is disabled.

This *is* Win7 64-bit.